# Logger inside android based on database

Tags: android

I am working on logs inside android, I thought two ways for storing logs, and one is on external directory as a text file or a log file while other is to store in database. I found database method more useful in my case. My question is if I UN-install and reinstall the app will the database will be affected?  In case of yes what should I do? I cannot place the logs online. How to take the backup or safe that database so it won’t be affected in case of UN- installation.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is if I uninstall and reinstall the app will the database will be affected?

Yes, your database will by default be stored in the application's data directory, which is deleted along with your application on uninstallation.

You can instead write a file of a filetype of your choosing (whether that's a simple text file, or a database file) to the external storage. You can obtain the directory path using:

1. [`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(type)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) for obtaining a directory path of files of a specific type, such as images or videos;
2. [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) for obtaining the primary external storage directory, under which you could create a new path.

I would nevertheless discourage you from doing this, because it would require your users to manually dispose of any files after uninstalling your application. Perhaps you should reconsider the justification of choosing for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you uninstall the app, then the database (and all other data stored in the apps private storage for that matter) will be gone.

You could store your logs in the public external storage, but this will expose your logs to other applications as well as the user.

One possible approach could be to use application private storage for your 'live' logs, and make periodic backups to the public storage. In case of a new installation, you can check your designated backup location and attempt to restore previous logs from the backup.